# how to disable touch event android

Tags: android, touch

How to disable touch event android?

Answer (score 10):

Do nothing but just return true in onTouchEvent().

If you are using any view, use android:clickable="false" as view's attribute in the xml.

Answer (score 3):

I solved like below,

```
 view.setClickable(true);
            view_activity.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (view_activity.isClickable()) {
                        if (isOpened)
                            closeMenu();
                 return false;
                    }
                else
                    return true;                    
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

if it's a View, you can use his method `setClickable(false)`